# Upgraded to Flutter 3.7.7 now can't run my app on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

When using flutter run I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following
dependencies
```

no dependencies are listed
using flutter run -v I get this:

```
[   +3 ms] Error (Xcode): [+3422 ms] Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following
dependencies
           
[   +6 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
[   +1 ms] Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
[   +7 ms] "flutter run" took 50 596ms.
[   +6 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:722:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1257:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:283:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem was shared_preferences Had to update it so it doesn't use an outdated version which caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove flutter_tools from your dependencies. It's too old and it does not support null safety.